# Include class oop php

Tags: php, ооп, классы, функции, include

Мне не совсем понятен один момент с ООП. Если я использую абстрактный класс, и пытаюсь в него подгрузить сторонний класс (не extends), находящийся в другом файле и делаю это через `__construct`, то мне выводится ошибка, `Class 'Foo' not found in ..`. А вот если подключаюсь к файлу в нужном методе, то все ок. Просто выглядит не очень красиво, если использовать по 10 раз в одном файле подключение к одному и тому же файлу, для 10 разных методов. Возможно ли использовать одно подключение в `__construct`-е?

Покажу на примере. Вот такой код выведет ошибку:

```
abstract class Name {
    public function __construct () {
        require_once 'Foo.php';
    }

    public function func1 () {
        $foo = new Foo;

        // ..
    }

    public function func2 () {
        $foo = new Foo;

        // ..
    }

    // и т.д.
}
```

А вот этот пример отлично отработает:

```
abstract class Name {
    public function __construct () {
        // ..
    }

    public function func1 () {
        require_once 'Foo.php';
        $foo = new Foo;

        // ..
    }

    public function func2 () {
        require_once 'Foo.php';
        $foo = new Foo;

        // ..
    }

    // и т.д.
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем собственно причина?

Comment: может область видимости? не?

Comment: А то, что вы в "нерабочем примере" поместили в конструктор доступно в других функциях?

Comment: а пути к файлам совпадают? сейчас накатал такой пример, все работает как вариант 1.

Comment: @Doigrales если использовать в extends этого класса (Name), те же самые методы, то работает, где подключение происходит в `__construct`. И не могу понять почему так происходит.

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, все пути верны, стоит только `require_once 'Foo.php';` перенести внутрь метода и все работает.

Comment: больше кода надо, где твой контроллер? как ты запускаешь Name?

Comment: @Jean-Claude если юзать `class AName extends Name {}` (а Name это абстрактный) то первый пример отрабатывает без ошибок. Но в абстрактном не хочет. С этим я раньше ни разу ни сталкивался и не знаю, как реагировать.

Comment: ну так ты и хотел чтобы первый пример работал, - сам только что сказал " первый пример отрабатывает без ошибок"

Comment: А если НЕ юзать "class AName extends Name {}", то как ты юзаешь?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude не так написал, в общем, если сократить код до минимума, то этот код отработает отлично `class AName extends Name {public function __construct() { require_once 'Foo.php'; } public function func1() { $foo = new Foo; }}` А вот внутри абстрактного класса не хочет работать.

Comment: @Doigrales но мне нужно юзать абстрактный класс, т.к. много чего туда подключено и логика работы уже так выстроена. Не охота все менять.

Comment: Я не программист PHP, но функцию-конструктор абстрактного класса надо же вызвать, верно?

Comment: @Doigrales это да, в полном коде там все вызывается. Но мне не хотелось скидывать весь код, т.к. это вряд ли кому-то будет интересно.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже дочерний класс должен вызывать функцию-конструктор родителя:

```
 abstract class Name {
    public function __construct () {
        require_once 'Foo.php'
        echo 'require_once called!';
    }

    public function func1 () {
        $foo = new Foo;
    }

    public function func2 () {
        $foo = new Foo;
    }
}

class AName extends Name {
   public function __construct () {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function func1 () {

    }

    public function func2 () {

    }
}

new AName(); //require_once called
```

Comment: Мне нужно юзать include для абстрактного класса, в дочернем там все ок.

Comment: @johndws в ответе require_once юзается в абстрактном классе как вы и хотите.